# Hierarchy getInstance() method in VF Page

Tags: visualforce, customsetting

Is it possible to use Hierachy custom setting `getInstance(userId)` method in VF Page?

I am trying to use below syntax but it is giving an error (Syntax error)

```
{!$Setup.customSetting__c.getValues(exampleUSerId).testField__c}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessing custom settings via `$Setup` always accesses the value set for the current context - i.e., the running user, inheriting settings as appropriate from the Profile and Organization levels.

From [$Setup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_setup.htm#!) in the Visualforce Developer Guide:

> Use $Setup to access hierarchical custom settings and their field values using dot notation. For example, $Setup.App_Prefs__c.Show_Help_Content__c.
>   Hierarchical custom settings allow values at any of three different levels:
>
> Organization, the default value for everyone
>      Profile, which overrides the Organization value
>      User, which overrides both Organization and Profile values
>
> Salesforce automatically determines the correct value for this custom setting field based on the running user’s current context.

You would need to use

```
{!$Setup.customSetting__c.testField__c}
```

and this would return the results for the current user context only.

Comment: Thanks, It tells that we can only get the custom setting value based on the current user context in VF and we cannot use methods in VF page. Is my understanding correct.

Comment: That is correct. You can call methods on the custom setting in your Apex controller, not in Visualforce markup.